# How do I add a variable for the textbox ID inside a function?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    double[] array = new double[5];
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            array[i] = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox(i+1).Text);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code, I have 5 textboxes, I'd like to refer to them with the int (i) inside the loop.

```
array[i] = Convert.ToDouble(TextBox(i+1).Text);
```

the text boxes are named 'TextBox1' , 'TextBox2', 'TextBox3, etc.

Is it possible in C#?

Comment: put the text boxes objects in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could if you use [Control.FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            TextBox currenTextBox = (TextBox) FindControl("TextBox" + i);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currenTextBox?.Text))
            {
                if (double.TryParse(currenTextBox.Text, out var result))
                {
                    array[i] = result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The only suggestion I would offer is to change the loop to start at i = 1 and have it go to < 6. This way you dont have to do i+1 to get the right textbox name.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the FindControl thingy, when I use it however, visual studio marks the .Text part at the end `.Text);` and says : **control does not contain a definition for 'Text'**, it doesn't let me run it.

Comment: @זיורוזוב Sorry, I wrote the code with notepad and not been very carefull, there was an error in the parenthesis order. FindControl() returns a Control class instance, TextBox's base class. So, you have to cast Control to TextBox to get access to Text property.  I have updated the code to reflect it and added some error handling.